# Handle exception and continue work without error

Tags: php, try-catch

I want to prevent situation when PHP throws an error in case of my bad or failed loading something (eg from remote server). Recently I started to using try-catch block to avoid fatal errors so user don't know that something is screwed up.

Look at my code:

```
try
{
    $flashRAW = file_get_contents($getXml);
    $flashXML = simplexml_load_string($flashRAW);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    return $e->getMessage();
}

$xmlString = $flashXML->asXML();
```

Using "return" is my invention (I think, I've never seen that...). With return my application will continue to work and I won't have "trying to get property on a non-object" error. Without return I will get it - I think it's stupid because I use try-catch to prevent this...

Is using return this way OK? Is better way to handle exception and make that application will continue work without fatal error? Somewhere I read that try-catch is intended to handle logic errors and increase memory consuming.

Comment: I have seen people use return in the catch block before, so its not a new invention. But what you could do (and should do) is log it in a file somewhere so an admin can see what problems your getting (include as much information as possible, userid, date/time, urls etc), and instead of returning, deal with the problem: Show an error message, tell them to contact an admin or to try again.

Comment: Do you think I can do that in a production environment? I think I shouldn't. Logging is of course OK but displaying errors to user IMHO isn't.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. Displaying errors is OK, as long as its nice error messages (i.e. "sorry the file you were looking for could not be found" or "sorry login failed, try again") not cryptic PHP error messages, they should never be displayed to end users.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue you are getting is becasue of '$flashRAW' not being defined if there is an exception.

You should check '$flashRAW' before calling '$flashXML->asXML()'.

If you use return no code executes in the function / page depending where you have your code.

Choice to use return or not is more based on Use Case. So depends how you use it.

Comment: I see. But this is just example. I assume that I should always check if there is an object in situation like that. Return is bad?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [libxml_use_internal_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) if you want to catch the exceptions it raises, do that before your `try/catch` block

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
```